# jQuery - function bound to resize event not working consistently

Tags: jquery, window-resize

I have some code that acts as a click toggle for a menu. I only want the code to run if the window width is under 768px, so I wrapped it in an if statement, that calculates the window width. I bound this function to the page resize event and page ready. It works some of the time but not others. Resize the results panel a few times and you'll see what I mean...

http://jsfiddle.net/agileapricot/LyUzr/

Comment: In my browser, the scrollbar is sometimes an issue -- at, say, 770px, if the full menu is shown, the scrollbar appears, which narrows the window, which causes the full menu to disappear again. Bit of a rare case, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not the key issue, but: `jQuery("#nav-btn a.togglemenu")` should be `jQuery("#nav a.togglemenu")`

You've added the click handler inside the `aaMenus` function, so this line:

```
jQuery(window).bind("resize", aaMenus);
```

...is running the function, and adding a *new* click hander, *every time the window is resized.* If the click handler has been added an even number of times, you're toggling on and off at the same time, with no visible result. Even if it's been added an odd number of times, you're running the toggle up to hundreds of times in a row, resulting in a huge delay.

All you need to do is take that click event handler out of your function:
http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/LyUzr/10/

```
function aaMenus() {
    if (jQuery(window).width() > 768) { // iPad and Desktop
        /* Dropdown Menu */
        jQuery("ul#menu").addClass("dropdown").removeClass("toggle").show();
        jQuery("a.togglemenu").hide();

        //.. Drop down function will go here later
    } else { // Mobiles
        /* Toggle menu */
        jQuery("ul#menu").addClass("toggle").removeClass("dropdown").hide();
        jQuery("a.togglemenu").show();
    }
}

jQuery(window).bind("resize", aaMenus);

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#nav a.togglemenu").click(function() {
        jQuery("ul.toggle").toggle();
    });
    aaMenus();
});
```

Comment: Yep. There is no element with id="nav-btn" in the example.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. I'm a js rookie as you can see :) I edited #nav-btn at the last minute before posting this, which explains why it wasn't working at all then, ha. Cheers.

Comment: @firefusion tweaked my answer just now -- be sure you put the click handler inside of `(document).ready` or it won't work.